# Blur CIImage as a CALayer Content image

Tags: objective-c, calayer

I am using bellow code for image blur. 'resultImage' shows the blurred image, but when I put it on a CALayer content It shows nothing.

```
CIImage *imageToBlur = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIGaussianBlur"];
[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:imageToBlur forKey: @"inputImage"];
[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 10] forKey: @"inputRadius"];
CIImage *resultImage = [gaussianBlurFilter valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
self.contents = resultImage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cantn't use `CIImage` as a content of `CALayer` . There might be some [VRM](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/305116-ciimage-directly-to-calayer-contents.html) issue. I dont no more about it. By the way you may use `CGImageRef` instead of `CIImage`. Based on your code the thing you can do ...

```
CIImage *imageToBlur = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIGaussianBlur"];
[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:imageToBlur forKey: @"inputImage"];
[gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 10] forKey: @"inputRadius"];
CIImage *resultImage = [gaussianBlurFilter valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
CIContext *cont = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef img = [cont createCGImage:resultImage fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
self.contents = (__bridge id)img;
```

I hope it'll work!